# Dynamic server side rendering with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, server-side-rendering

All the SSR tutorials for React that I've seen use `React.hydrate` on a component that already has all of its data or doesn't need any props, i.e., `React.hydrate(<Home />, document.getElementById('root'))`.

My problem is that `<Home />` actually needs to take in a prop, namely `:promoId`, upon my route on the server being called.

i.e., I have a certain route:

```
v1/promos/:promoId
```

and I need to get the params from this route and feed it into the `hydrate` method upon it being called, but to my understanding, this is not possible.

Has anyone solved a problem like this?

Comment: a framework that answers this and other questions
https://github.com/americanexpress/one-app

Comment: @DayanMorenoLeon unfortunately I can not use a framework for this case

Comment: NextJs also allows this. Look into their code base to see their solution?

Comment: @SILENT good idea, thanks! hopefully can dig enough to find it

Comment: @Turk were you able to find some solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Was able to solve this by using the window object.

i.e.,

`React.hydrate(<Home promo={window.__INITIAL__DATA__.promo} />, document.getElementById('root'))`

and then in my server file, in the method that handles `v1/promos/:promoId`, all I have to do is: `WINDOW.__INITIAL_DATA__.promo = params.promoId`